Every positive integer can be written as a sum of distinct integral powers of $\varphi$ if $\varphi^a+\varphi^b=2$

Let $\varphi$ be a positive real number. Assume there exist distinct (not necessarily positive) integers $a$ and $b$ such that $\varphi^a+\varphi^b=2.$ Show that each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ can be written as a sum of $n$ distinct integral powers of $\varphi.$

My Work:
Note that $\varphi^0=1.$ So, the case of $n=1$ is trivial. The case of $n=2$ is also settled as $\varphi^a+\varphi^b=2$ and we are given that $a≠b.$
Now, suppose $a=0.$ Then, $\varphi^b=1.$ Since $a≠b,$ we conclude that $\varphi=1.$ Similarly, if $b=0,$ we get that $\varphi=1.$ In this case, the problem is trivial. Hence, hereafter, we may assume that $a$ and $b$ are non-zero. This gives us an admissible representation for $3$ as we have $\varphi^a+\varphi^b+\varphi^0=3.$
I'm not sure how to proceed though. I think induction may help.
Remark: There's a very interesting non-trivial example. Let $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$ Then, $\varphi^{-2}+\varphi^1=2.$ So the above result applies.
Note: In a previous version of this question, I had incorrectly solved this for $n=4.$ I've edited that out.

Have you tried to use the binary representation of the integers? If you can prove that such an expression exists for all powers of $2$, it might be possible to represent all the integers this way.

@UmeshShankar not sure if I follow your logic. Say I represent $n$ as $2^u + 2^v$ for distinct $u,v$. Now I write $2^u$ and $2^v$ in their "admissible representation" as a sum of distinct powers of $\varphi.$ What ensures that there's no "overlap" between these two representations? What if $\varphi^6$ shows up in both of them, for example?

What we get from the answers so far is that the problem can be restated in a completely non-algebraic way: consider a pile of $n$ chips placed in a single cell of a (two-sided) infinite array of cells, and let a move consist of taking two chips from the same cell and moving one of them $-a$ places to the left and the other $b$ places to the right, prove that after a finite number of moves all cells contain at most one chip. This doesn't yet solve it but it strongly suggests (for me at least) that we shouldn't see this as an algebraic problem at all.

@R.P. FYI That's how I reskinned the problem when I thought about it. Again it seems "obvious", esp in the $a < 0 < b$ case, but even then that was hard to get to a rigorous proof. I couldn't do a "direct" proof. $\quad$ It definitely was surprising to me that the $ 0 < a < b$ case sometimes could not be done.

@CalvinLin I do think your proof can be restated in a non-algebraic way, without turning it into something artificial. But I first want to think about it longer before I write more, because my thinking is muddled today and I don't want to write any more nonsense.

@R.P. Oh, it can be. It's just about mono variances and bounded sequences in Observations 6+. (IE Consecutive boxes are at most $b+|a|$ apart, and any path that randomly splits coefficients will eventually work). We do have to use arithmetic calculations, but nothing algebraic like polynomial division. $\quad$ Side note: I believe that the final distribution is unique, via the polynomial division interpretation (which I didn't delve too much into). Also, I would like a non-algebraic proof that the $0 < a < b$ case sometimes could not be done.

What's the source of this interesting question?

@Ѕᴀᴀᴅ, I saw this asked on quora. But I'm not able to find the question on quora now.

For $\varphi>1$ and $\varphi^a+\varphi^b=2$ with $a>0$ we have the following result:-
THEOREM Any sum, $s$ say, of $n$ integer powers of $\varphi$ can be made with $n$ distinct integers.
PROOF The result is trivial for $n=1$ so we can assume the result is true for any sum of $n-1$ integer powers.
Of all the sums equal to $s$ choose one containing the largest integer power, $m$ say. (Note that the integer powers are bounded by $M$ where $\varphi^M=s$)
Consider $s-\varphi^m$. This is the sum of $n-1$ integer powers and can therefore be made with distinct integers. To this sum add $\varphi^m$.
If $\varphi^m$ is now used twice then we could replace $\varphi^m+\varphi^m$ by $\varphi^{m+a}+\varphi^{m+b}$ which contradicts the maximality of $m$. We have therefore obtained the requisite sum using distinct integers.
APPLICATION $n$ can be expressed using $n$ zero powers and can therefore be expressed using $n$ distinct integers.

I think this time around you've got it right (however when you write "choose the one containing the largest integer power" this is strictly speaking incorrect, since there can be multiple possible choices -- but it doesn't matter, since you can pick an arbitrary one and the argument you give will work).

Very nice theorem. Love it when a generalization of the problem leads to a simpler solution.

@R.P. Yes it is better to say "one" not the "one".

We suppose $0\neq b$ WLOG.
Let us show this by induction, we set:
$$\mathcal P_k: \, \forall n < 2^k, \, \exists r^n_1<\dots<r_n^n  \in \mathbb N; \, n = \sum_{j=1}^n \varphi^{r_j^n}$$
and each of these $r^n_j \in a\mathbb N + b \mathbb N =: M$
Of course $\mathcal P_0$ is true since $0$ is the empty sum.
Let us now suppose $\mathcal P_k$ is true, and let $2^k\le n < 2^{k+1}$, then $m = n-2^k < 2^k$.
We have
$$\begin{align}
2^k &= (\varphi^a + \varphi^b)^k\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^k c_i^k \varphi^{ia + (k-i)b}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^k \sum_{j=1}^{c^k_i} \varphi^{r^{c_{i}^k}_j + ia + (k-i)b}
\end{align}$$

Here $c_j^k = \binom kj$ and since their sum is $2^k$ and there are at least two non-zero summands, all are strictly smaller than $2^k$.

This is a sum of exactly $\sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki = 2^k$ powers of $\varphi$ (not necessarily distinct), with indices all in $M$.
Now since $m$ is the sum of $m$ powers of $\varphi$, $n = m + 2^k$ is the sum of $m + 2^k = m$ powers of $\varphi$.
Now we need to find an algorithm to get rid of the multiplicities in the sum, but this is very hard since we need to prove termination…
The main idea is replace any $2 \cdot \varphi^c$ by $\varphi^{c+a}+ \varphi^{c+b}$, but the question is in what order must we deal with them. A good case disjunction would be $a,b$ of the same Saigon and $a,b$ of opposite sign.
What I can achieve now is get to a sum where all the multiplicites are smaller or equal to $2$.

Now to find non trivial examples we need to find $\varphi^a +\varphi^b=2$ it has no non trivial positive roots of both are positive so we will suppose one (at least) is negative and $a>b$.
This is equivalent to finding the positive roots of polynomials of the form:
$$x^{a-b} - 2x^{-b} +1=0$$
We replace $c = a-b$ and $d=-b$ this gives
$$x^c-2x^d+1$$
We get rid of the trivial root in $1$ by an Euclidean division by $X-1$ we get
$$x^{c-1} + \dots + x^{d} -x^{d-1} - \cdots -1$$
Which is worth $a+b$ in $1$ and $-1$ in $0$.

If $a+b>0$ we have at least one non trivial root between $0$ and $1$ but no roots grater than $1$.
If $a+b<0$ then we have roots that may lie everywhere in $\mathbb R_+$.
If $a+b=0$ this is troublesome since of the multiple roots of $1$ so we better study the positive $a-th$ roots of the roots of $x^2-2x+1 = (x-1)^2$ but they are all equal to $1$!


Your note about the Fibonacci conjecture reminds me of Guy's "Law of Small Numbers," which deserves wider awareness. See https://3quarksdaily.com/3quarksdaily/2016/12/human-beings-have-a-talent-for-spotting-patterns-no-doubt-this-was-a-handy-skill-to-have-in-our-early-days-if-both-ug-and-o.html .

@JohnHughes very interesting article, even for non-mathematicians! I had already read about a study were people were asked to spot random distribution on a target and they were almost always wrong!

1/ Can you explain why "After $q$ steps, we have $c_{l+q} > c_q$? " How do you know that the minimum offender index is increased, esp if $ a < 0$? $\quad$ 2/ Can you explain why " we have $c_{l+q} > c_l$, thus $s_{l+q} < s_l$"? If the minimum offender index is increased, why does that imply that the number of offenders has decreased? $\quad$ 3/ note that $s_{l+q} < s_l$ doesn't imply that $s_l$ must always be decreasing. We could have $s_{l+1} > s_l$. But yes, otherwise you would have shown that some $s_k = 0$.

4/ "If $f_l(c+a)=0$ or $f_l(c+b) = 0$ the number of "problems to deal withs" diminishes, i.e. $s_{l+1} < s_l$." is not true. Even if they were both 0, then if $f_l (c) \geq 4$, you end up with $f_{l+1} ( c+a) \geq 2, f_{l+1}( c+b) \geq 2$ so you increased the number of offenders. $\quad$ A close reading of your solution suggests to me that you've swept a lot of the technical details under the rug. They do need to be addressed.

@CalvinLin I modified it in the train the original was better I thought the new version was easier but it is false but I don’t know how to get back to the previous version

@CalvinLin it should be good I found on the meta how to do it

Also I’m French so I use decreasing in the weak sense (non increasing)

Édit: I fixed the original algo to fit the negative case

My concerns are still valid and you've not really addressed them. To me, the details need to be checked, and you're just sweeping them under the rug with your very general statements.  $\quad$  1 + 4 revisited/ "If $f_l(c+a)=0$ or $f_l(c+b) = 0$ the number of "problems to deal withs" diminishes, i.e. $s_{l+1} < s_l$." As explained before, this is not true. if $f_l (c) > 3$, then making 1 move doesn't make it a non-offender, AND if either of $f_l(c+a) , f_l(c+b) \geq 1$, then they become a NEW offender, so $ s_{l+1} > s_l$.

5/ "If for each step $l' \ge l$, $f(c+a)>0$ and $f(c+b) > 0$, .So if at each step this is the case this means that $C = {d\ge c \in M \mid f_l(d) >0}$ contains $c + b \mathbb N$ which means $C$ is infinite.  " This is very poorly written. Your $c$ doesn't stay the same at each step, so you might want to use $c_l$? Also, here is no reason why $c_{l+k} = c + i b$, or each $ c+ib + (k-i) a$. Your $c_l$ was defined as the minimum offender, so after fixing $c_l$, we might have to deal with  $c_l + 1$ as the new minimum offender.

(Minor points) 6/  In the $a+b < 0 $ case, the non-1 root is $ > 1$. The range is NOT $> 0$.  $\quad$ 7/ The step of induction on $P_k$ isn't that relevant, since we have $ n = n \varphi^0$ as the sum of (not necessarily distinct) powers of $ \varphi$. If you used that the coefficients were $ \leq \log_2 n$, then maybe that induction could be relevant.  $\quad$

@CalvinLin I agree the writing is a bit confused but I modified the algorithm to deal with these problems, however since I did it rapidly it may be ambiguous. I’ll try to give more precision asap. For the 2^k bound it is not necessary but it helps figuring out the mechanics. Also it seems there is a problem for the case $f(c)=2$

Unfortunately you're introducing more issues. EG Even though $f_l$ has finitely many non-zero values, when you're looking at $f_l'$, each of them could have a slightly different support. In fact, if we could indefinitely "split" a coefficient each them, then we could potentially have that $c + b \mathbb{N}$ structure that you're thinking of. So your argument is circular - by assuming we can't indefinitely split, you show that we cannot indefinitely split. $\quad$ FWIW To me, this is one question where the devil is in the details.

As further evidence that this solution doesn't always work out, if you consider doing this for $x^3 + x^2 = 2$, WITHOUT recognizing that the only real root is $x = 1$, once you end up with some $2x^k + 2x^{k+1} + x^{k+2}$ (EG $n=7$), then the coefficient split happens infinitely as we will endlessly loop. This is because $(x^3 + x^2 - 2) / (x-1) = x^2 + 2x + 2$. Thus, we need to use that $ a < 0 < b$, as per my solution.

@CalvinLin Yes I was exactly dealing with this case considering $M = a\wedge b \mathbb Z$ but unfortunately I did not have a lot of time to deal with it. I had remarked some loops in the pattern but I did not know how to get rid of them

So it sounds to me that 1/ You knew there were issues with your proof, 2/ You proceeded to present the proof as if there were no issues, 3/ When I brought up various issues, you merely shrugged them away, 4/ Only when I brought up a counter example, did you admit that there are issues. $\quad$ I find this behavior very dishonest, and you're just trying to collect upvotes from people who do not read in detail. At the very least, I'd encourage you to post a disclaimer at the top of your solution. But you do what you want. I'm out of this conversation.

@CalvinLin I only had a few minutes to check it on my phone throughout the wk, I honestly don’t really care about votes. Your remarks were well founded but with only quick glimpses I initially failed to see all the flaws. I already deleted the problematics parts and planned to put a complete proof but I won’t have time to do it before a week. Don’t take everything very personally, I just don’t have a lot of free time. Usually I quickly deal with my mistakes but rn it’s complicated. I left it open since it was the only partial until then. I also upvoted your valid solution as soon as I saw it.

Replacing $\varphi$ by $\varphi^{-1}$, if needed, we suppose that $\varphi\ge 1$. Moreover, we suppose $\varphi>1$ because if $\varphi=1$ then $n=\varphi^1+\dots+\varphi^n$ is a required representation. Suppose that $a<b$. Then $a<0<b$.
Fix a natural number $n$. Let $S$ be the family of all sequences $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ of nonnegative integers such that $a_k=0$ for all but finitely many $k$ and $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} a_k=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} a_k\varphi^k=n.$$ Calvin Lin noted that the set $S$ is nonempty, because it contains the sequence $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ such that $a_0=n$ and $a_k=0$ for each $k\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. Let $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z},(a'_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}\in S$ be any distinct sequences. Let $K=\max_{k\in\mathbb Z} a_k\ne a'_k$. We put $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}< (a'_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ if $a_K<a'_K$.
We claim that any increasing infinite chain $(a^1_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}<(a^2_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}<\dots $ of sequences of $S$ stabilizes. Indeed, we have $a^i_k\le \frac{n}{\varphi^k}$ for each natural $i$ and and integer $k$. Moreover, since $\varphi>1$ then there exists a natural number $K$ such that $\varphi^K\ge n$. Then $a^i_k=0$ for each natural $i$ and $k\ge K$. Now suppose that $i$ increases. Then the biggest natural $k$ such that $a^i_k\ne 0$ and the value of this $a^i_k$ stabilizes, next the second biggest natural $k$ such that $a^i_k\ne 0$ and the value of this $a^i_k$ stabilizes, and so forth up to the $n$th biggest natural $k$ such that $a^i_k\ne 0$ and the value of this $a^i_k$.
Now we can construct a required representation by induction. Pick an arbitrary sequence $(a^1_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}\in S$. If at an $i$th induction step for all integer $k$ the number $a^i_k$ is either $0$ or $1$ then $(a^i_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ is a required representation. Otherwise pick any integer $k$ such that $a^i_k\ge 2$ and put $a^{i+1}_k=a^i_k-2$, $a^{i+1}_{k+a}=a^i_{k+a}+1$, $a^{i+1}_{k+b}=a^i_{k+b}+1$, and $a^{i+1}_j=a^i_j$ for all $j\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{k,k+a,k+b\}$.
Since $b>0$, $(a^i_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}<(a^{i+1}_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}$. Since any increasing infinite chain of elements of $S$ stabilizes, the inductive construction will stop at some step, providing a required representation.
PS. Let $s$ be a sum of $n$ integer powers of $\varphi$. If in the definition of $S$ we replace the condition $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} a_k=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} a_k\varphi^k=n$$ by the condition
$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} a_k=n\mbox{ and }\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} a_k\varphi^k=s$$
then we can similarly prove a more general claim that $s$ is a sum of $n$ distinct integer powers of $\varphi$, which, as I understood, is stated and proved in user1172706's answer. But, anyway, user1172706's proof is more simple than mine.

Ah, very nice proof with this increasing sequence.

@CalvinLin Thanks for your observation, I added it to the answer. Also thanks for your kind words and the attention to my answer. Although it fits for contest-math, it looks too simple, taking into accounts the above tries. Nevertheless, I see no errors in my answer. On the other hand, here is about 4:30 am. ;-)

The increasing chain idea is standard and I had it a couple of days ago. But I refused it because I was afraid that a chain can contain infinitely many sequences with nonzero members with negative indexes of arbitrarily big absolute value. But now I realized that the number of nonzero members of each sequence is at most $n$, that justifies the chain finiteness argument from the answer.

I also had that idea, but I got too caught up with "unbounded minimum exponent" issue. In hindsight, I could have worked around my Observation 8 by showing that "Clearly there are finitely many possible sets of coefficients on the positive exponents"

I'd say the two proofs (this one and the one by @user1172706) are very similar, but this proof sets up a bit more machinery than is needed (you don't need the total order on the set of sequences, just the partial order given by the maximum degree). So if the other proof is slightly better,  it is because it is more economical.

Preamble: This solution is much more technical than I would have expected it to be at the start. If we can split the coefficients, we should be able to push them far enough apart, right?
When I tried proving it, I ended up making similar claims of "surely we can make this happen". However, the reasoning was circular, and led to numerous issues, some of which I pointed out in the comments in Julios solution.
As it turns out, that thinking was too naive and isn't true. The naive manipulation is equivalent to treating this just as question on polynomials. Then, when attempting $2 = x^2 + x^3$, we run into problems for $n = 8$. We can show that (by induction and splitting coefficients as needed):
$$\begin{array} { l r r r r r r r r r r} 
1 & = & x^0 \\
2 & = &     &     & x^2 & + x^3\\
3 & = & x^0 &     & + x^2 & + x^3\\
4 & = & & & & & x^4 & & + x^6 & + x^7 & + x^8 \\
5 & = & x^0 &  & & & +x^4 & & + x^6 & + x^7 & + x^8 \\
6 & = & &  &x^2 &+x^3 & + x^4 & & + x^6 & + x^7 & + x^8 \\
7 & = & x^0 &  &+x^2 &+x^3 & + x^4 & & + x^6 & + x^7 & + x^8 \\
\end{array}$$
When we consider $8$, and split the $2x^0$, we end up with $2x^2  + 2x^3 + x^4$ at the start. Splitting the $2x^2, 2x^3$ then gives us $2x^4 + 2x^5 + x^6$, and this would keep on continuing to ever higher powers. While it doesn't immediately imply that there is no solution for $n=7$ (since it requires a specific path of splitting), but it highlights some of the potential issues. In the  postamble below, I prove that this is not possible. Any solution would have to address this issue that naive splitting doesn't work for certain polynomials. In particular, any solution that could work for $ x^3 + x^2 = 2$ is thus incorrect..

Outline of the solution:
We will work with the power series $ \sum_{- \infty} ^ \infty a_i x^i$, where the exponents are allowed to be negative integers.
Starting from $ f_1 = n x^0$, whenever a coefficient of $x^k$ is $ \geq 2$, we will split $2x^k$ and replace it with $ x^{k+a} +x^{k+b}$. If there are multiple coefficients that are $\geq 2$, we will not exert any control over which one is chosen to be split.
We will let this sequence of polynomials be denoted as $ f_j (x) = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_{i, j} x^i$.
Observe that $f_j(1) = n$ and $f_j (\varphi) = n$ by definition.
If this sequence terminates, then we have written $n$ as the sum of $n$ distinct powers of $ \varphi$.

(Observation 1-5) Strip away the problematic aspects, restrict to $ a < 0 < b$ and $|a| > |b|$.
(Observation 6-9) Show that there are finitely many power series that satisfy $f_j(1) = n, f_j ( \varphi) = n$, and could arise from the splitting process, by bounding the exponents.
(Observation 10) Show that the sequence $f_j$ is unique.
(Observation 11) Hence, the sequence must eventually terminate. This means that we can no longer split a coefficient, so they are all 0 or 1. Thus, we have written $n$ as the sum of $n$ distinct powers of $ \varphi$.

Solution:
Observation 1. If $ \varphi = 1$, then OP showed that the statement is true.
Observation 2. If $ ab = 0 $, then OP showed that the statement is true.
Observation 3. If $ab > 0$, then the only positive root of $ \varphi^a + \varphi^b = 2$ is $ \varphi = 1$, so we are done.
Thus, the interesting case is $ab < 0$. WLOG $a < 0 < b$ (else replace $(a, b)$ with $(b, a)$).
Observation 4.  If $|a| = |b|$, then the only positive root of $ \varphi^{2b} - 2\varphi^b + 1 = (\varphi^b - 1)^2 $ is $ \varphi = 1$, so we are done.
Observation 5. If $|a| \neq |b|$, then by Descarte Rule of signs,
$$\frac{ \varphi^{b-a} - 2 \varphi^{-a} + 1 } { \varphi - 1 } = \varphi^{b-a-1} + \varphi^{b-a-2} + \ldots + \varphi^{-a} - \varphi^{-a-1} - \varphi^{-a-2} - \ldots - 1  $$
has a unique positive root.
If $|a| < |b|$, then this root is $< 1$. Furthermore, the root is also $ > \frac{1}{2}$, but we will not need to use this fact.
Conversely, if $|a| > |b|$, then this root is $> 1$.  Furthermore, the root is also $ < 2$, but we will not need to use this fact.
WLOG $|a| > |b|$ (else replace $(a, b)$ with $(-b, -a)$), so $ \varphi > 1$.
Now, let's consider all power series whose coefficient satisfy  $ \sum a_i = n$ and $ \sum a_i \varphi^i = n$ that might have arisen in the sequence $f_j$. We do so by calculating restrictions on $f_j$ (Observation 6-8).
Observation 6. The maximum exponent is $ \leq \log_\phi n$.
Observation 7. If all of the exponents are negative, then $ n=\sum a_i \varphi^i < \sum a_i = n$  is a contradiction. Hence, at least one of the exponent is non-negative.
(Similarly, at least one of the exponents is non-positive.)
Observation 8. Since each time we split an exponent, we move it only by $-|a|, +b$, it should be intuitive that the exponents remain close to each other. Specifically, if $ f_j(x) = x^{b_1} + x^{b_2} + x^{b_3} + \ldots +  x^{b_n}$ with $ b_1 \leq b_2 \leq \ldots \leq b_n$, then $b_{i+1} - b_i  \leq b-a$.
Since there is a non-negative exponent, thus the minimum exponent is $ \geq -n(b-a)$ is bounded. (Likewise, this gives us a bound on the maximum exponent $\leq n(b-a)$, but observation 6 is much easier to get and stronger too.)
This might be the trickiest/non-obvious part, so I shall include a detailed proof.

 It suffices to show that for any exponent with non-zero coefficient, there is (at least) one exponent with non-zero coefficient that occurs at most $b-a$ before it, and (at least) one  exponent with non-zero coefficient that occurs at most $b-a$ after it.

 We proceed by induction.
 The base case of $ nx^0$ is trivial.

 For the induction step, we just need to consider the split coefficient $x^{b_i} = x^{b_{i+1} } $ that is moved to $x^{b_i - |a|}$ and $x^{b_i + b } $,  and it's neighbors.

 Let's focus on $x^{b_{i-1}}$, with a similar result for $x^{b_{i+2}}$.
 Lower: $x^{b_{i-2}}$ will work.
 Upper: If $ b_i - |a| < b_{i-1}$, then $x^{b_{i-2} } $ will work. Otherwise, $x^{b_i - |a| }$ will work.

 Let's focus on $x^{b_i -| a| } $, with a similar result for $x^{b_i + b } $.
 Lower: If $ b_i - |a| < b_{i-1}$, then $x^{b_{i-2} } $ will work. Otherwise, $x^{b_{i-1}}$ will work.
 Upper: $b_i + b$ will work.

Observation 9. Since the exponents are bounded, hence we have finitely many power series with coefficient sum of $n$, that may arise as potential $f_j$.
Observation 10. Since $b \geq 1$, so $ 2 \times 2 ^k \leq 2^{k+b} <  2^{k+a} + 2^{k+b}$, so $f_j(2)$ is an increasing sequence. In particular, $f_j \neq f_k$.
Observation 11. Since we have finitely many power series, and the sequence may not loop back on itself, hence eventually this sequence must terminate.
Corollary: Hence, we have written $n$ as the sum of $n$ distinct powers of $ \varphi$.

Postamble: Proof that $(a, b, n) = (2, 3, 8)$ has no naive splitting coefficients proof.
Lemma: $ g_j (x) = \frac{ f_j(x) - 8}{x^3 + x^2 - 2 }$ is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients.
This follows from

$g_1 (x) = 0 $.
At step $i$, if we replace $ 2x^k$ with $ x^{k+3} + x^{k+2}$, then $ g_{i+1} (x) = g_{i} (x) + x^k $.

Now, suppose $ f_j(x) - 8  = ( x^3 + x^2 - 2) (\sum a_i x^i)$, then let's find the coefficients $a_i$

Looking at the $x^0$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 8 = -2(a_0)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_ 0 = 4$
Looking at the $x^1$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - 4(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 0 = -2(a_1)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_1 = 0$.
Looking at the $x^2$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - 4(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 4 = -2(a_2)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_2 = 2$.
Looking at the $x^3$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 4 = -2(a_3)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_3 = 2$.
Looking at the $x^4$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2+2x^3)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 2 = -2(a_4)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_4 = 1$.
Looking at the $x^5$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2+2x^3+x^4)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 4 = -2(a_5)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_5 = 2$.
Looking at the $x^6$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2+2x^3+x^4+2x^5)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 3 = -2(a_6)$, hence we have to use 1, and $a_6 = 1$.
Looking at the $x^7$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2+2x^3+x^4+2x^5 + x^6)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 3 = -2(a_7)$, hence we have to use 1, and $a_7 = 1$.
Looking at the $x^8$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2+2x^3+x^4+2x^5 + x^6+x^7)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 3 = -2(a_8)$, hence we have to use 1, and $a_8 = 1$.
At this point, we have $ f(x) = x^6 + x^7 + x^8 + \sum x^{b_i} $ (higher order terms).

Since $x^3 + x^2 - 2 = ( x -1 ) (x^2 + 2x + 2)$, hence $ \frac{ f(x) - 8 } { x^2 + 2x + 2 } $ is also a polynomial.
Notice that $\frac{x^8 + x^7  + x^6 - 8 }{ x^2 + 2x + 2} = x^6 - x^5 + x^4  - 2x^2 + 4x - 4 $, so $ \frac{ \sum x^{b_i} } { x^2 + 2x + 2} $ is a polynomial.
So the smallest exponent with non-zero coefficient (which is 1) must be even, thus we have a contradiction. This means that there are no larger terms.
However, $ \frac{ x^8 + x^7 + x^6 - 8 } { x^3 + x^2 - 2} = x^5 + x^3 + x^2 - x + 3 + \frac{ -x^2 - 2x - 2 } { x^3 + x^2 - 2 } $ is not a polynomial.


Note that we cannot stick to using $x^3 + x^2 - 2$ in the denominator. (Or at least, I cannot get a contradiction that way.)

Furthermore, this approach works for $ n = 9, 10, 11, 12, 13$.

How do you get $6=1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6$ from $2=x^2+x^3$? That does follow if $x$ is a positive real (as in the original question), because then $x=1$. But if you only use splitting, then $2=x^2+x^3$ is consistent with $x=i-1$, whereas the decomposition of $6$ is not

@A.Rex Fixed the multiple typos. I meant $ (x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 -6) / (x^3 + x^2 - 2) = x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 3$ per Wolfram. Also added a bit more details.

@CalvinLin Do you really need Observation 6? It looks like the crucial ingredients in the proof are that the $f_i$ are unique, and that they are contained in a finite set of polynomials. Moreover the last fact follows from the further observations that one of the exponents must be positive, and that the spacing between consecutive monomials is bounded. I don't see where the bound on the highest exponent comes in.

@R.P. We do need to bound the possible exponents, so that $f_l$ is finite.  Like I said (typo fixed), with observation 7+8 we can also bound the max exponent by $ n(b-a)$, but observation 6 is much more immediate. (I was debating including it, I went with it partly because it demonstrated how I approached the problem.)

Okay, I think your solution is great and deserves to be accepted. I deleted my previous comment where I said that for $\varphi$ satisfying $\varphi^3+\varphi^2=2$ we have $8=\varphi^6+\varphi^7+\varphi^8$, which is true as long as we also require $\varphi \neq 1$, but it isn't really relevant for this problem because we want to write $8$ as a sum of exactly $8$ distinct powers of $\varphi$, not fewer. (But I found it interesting anyway.)

@R.P. (Saw the edit) Right, we also require $f(1) = n$ (which is a necessary condition for the numerator to be a multiple of $x-1$ by Remainder Factor Theorem). $\quad$ In your example, we do have $ (x^8 + x^7 + x^6 - 8 ) / ( x^2 + 2x + 2 ) $ is a polynomial, BUT $ (x^8 + x^7 + x^6 - 8 ) / (x^3 + x^2 - 2 )$ is not a polynomial as it leaves a remainder of $-x^2 - 2x - 2$. So it doesn't work.

The example $x^3+x^2=2$ is only a problem if we allow $\varphi$ to be non-real, but question states it's a real number, so why bother with this case? Then since $\varphi=1$ is solved trivially, remaining cases work just fine by the "splitting" method (to me the only problematic part seems to be showing the exponents are bounded from below).

@Sil The reason is that there are several "solutions" on here which would still "work" for the $ 0 < a < b$ counterexample where we consider them as polynomials, without the non-1 real number requirement. This definitively proves that such a solution is flawed,  even if they are unwilling to admit that there's a gap in their reasoning / engage with the criticism (See the extensive comments that I've left on several solutions).  $\quad$ Had my history of answering this question been different, I would have written up a very different answer. There was a lot of "groundwork" that I had to lay.

ACKNOWLEDGEMENT This revised proof generalises the entire idea of the original post. It has been possible to simplify the original proof by using an idea of @Calvin Lin.
DEFINITIONS For any multiset of integers, $S$, let $l(S)$ denote the least member and $t(S)$ the sum of all members.
A multiset of integers $x_1\le….\le x_n$ will be said to be $d$-bounded if each $x_{i+1}-x_i \le d$.
For integers a and b and a finite multiset, $S$, we will say $S$ can be $(a,b)$-mapped to $T$ if $T$ can be formed from $S$ by replacing two integers $x,x$ by $x+a,x+b$.
THEOREM Let $a$ and $b$ be integers such that $ab<0$ and let $S$ be any multiset of $n$ integers. Then either the members of $S$ are distinct or there is a sequence of $(a,b)$-mappings from $S$ to a multiset with all members distinct.
OUTLINE PROOF First we will prove the result in the special case that $S$ is $(a-b)$-bounded with $a>0$ and $a+b>0$. We can suppose that $S$ has two equal members $x,x$ and let $T$ be formed by replacing these integers by $x+a,x+b$.
Note that:

$l(T)\le l(S)$
$T$ is $(a-b)$-bounded
$t(T)=t(S)+a+b>t(S)$
Each element of $T$ is at most $l+(n-1)(a-b)$ and so $t(T)\le nl+n(n-1)(a-b)$

From 3. and 4. we see that successively repeating this process gives a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers which are bounded above. The process must therefore terminate and this only happens when a multiset is reached with all members distinct.
To extend this proof to $a+b=0$ requires noting that in this case the sum of squares of members is strictly increasing. Multiplying all the integers by $-1$ deals with the case $a+b<0$.
A general multiset of integers splits in a natural way into one or more $(a-b)$-bounded multisets. Each $(a,b)$-mapping then acts on just one of these subsets. The proof is essentially the same except that the process may now involve subsets combining before termination.
NOTE For each pair of integers such that $ab>0$, there are initial multisets of integers which cannot be changed into a set of distinct integers by a sequence of $(a,b)$-mappings. For these multisets, the process never terminates and the maximum (or minimum) element increases (or decreases) without limit.

@Calvin Lin. I have been thinking about exactly what is happening in this problem and realised the importance of your Observation 8. As in the above revised proof this  totally removes ϕ from the proof.

This is much better now and I've deleted the previous comments. $\quad$ This question turned out to be much trickier than I expected with a lot of potential pitfalls, but also resulted in a lot of nice results. Thanks for powering through this.
